# Convert String in milliseconds to Date Object (JAVA)

Tags: java

Is there a way for me to convert a String in milliseconds to a Date object?

In my program, I have to convert a Date in MM/dd/yyyy format to milliseconds, but then I have to pass that to a Date object.

Below, `dateStringFinal` is a String with the format "MM/dd/yyyy" already.

```
Calendar dateInCal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    try {
        dateInCal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateStringFinal));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
String dateInMilli = String.valueOf(dateInCal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Then I have to set a date variable

```
someBean.setBeginDate(dateInMilli);
```

But `dateInMilli` should be a Date object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new Date(Long.valueOf(dateInMs));
```

However, `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` already returns a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Long.parseLong(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29):

```
someBean.setBeginDate(Long.parseLong(dateInMilli));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Date` immediately from calendar with `calendar.getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

dateInCal.getTimeInMillis() returns Long. keep it in Long instead of String. And then use Date constructor that takes Long:

```
Long dateInMilli = dateInCal.getTimeInMillis();
someBean.setBeginDate(new Date(dateInMilli));
```